# addPreferencesFromResource in Class without OnCreate

Tags: java, android

I am somewhat new to Android.. it possible to load the preferences.xml/settings.xml without an onCreate? I was trying to pass the context to it but I can not find a way to do this..

Here is my code:

```
public class SettingsClass extends PreferenceFragment {

    public SettingsClass( ) { }

    public void ChangeSettings() {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
    public boolean LoadSettings( Activity activity )
    {
        TextView textMain= (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textMain);
        textMain.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

        String textsize = sp.getString("textsize", null);
        if( textsize != null ) {
            textMain.setTextSize( Integer.parseInt( textsize ) );
        }
        String transparency = sp.getString("transparency", null);
        if( transparency != null )  {
            textMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(transparency));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make this so I can easily load the class, and settings at MainActivity start.

```
final SettingsClass set = new SettingsClass();

set.LoadSettings();
```

Then if the user wishes to change these settings he/she can click a button which calls:

```
set.ChangeSettings();
```

However, this code is crashing and I can't seem to find a solution.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this way.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    static public void LoadSettings( Activity activity )
    {
        TextView textMain= (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textMain);
        textMain.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

        String textsize = sp.getString("textsize", null);
        if( textsize != null ) {
            textMain.setTextSize( Integer.parseInt( textsize ) );
        }
        String transparency = sp.getString("transparency", null);
        if( transparency != null )  {
            textMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(transparency));
        }
    }
}
```

So, to load settings call SettingsActivity.LoadSettings(this); It will not use the OnCreate. To edit the settings, simply intent to call the activity onCreate and the XML file.

```
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Thanks!